# Excel VBA- Compare Columns for matching

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am trying to compare two tables on the same excel sheet. Following is what i am trying to achieve. This has to be done in excel VBA.

```
A   B   C   D       E           F   G   H       I        J         
E1  40  1   4   4/16/2017       E4  30       11/1/2017
E2  20  1   5   6/22/2016       E2  20       11/1/2017
E3  10  0   4   6/30/2017       E1  40       10/31/2017
E4  30  1   6   3/10/2015       E3  10       10/31/2017
```

TASK 1

```
If A matches F (Equipment numbers match)
AND
If B matches G (ID-Numbers match)
AND 
If column C=1 (Equipment is in Service. C=0 means not in service)

Then
Update (copy/ paste) Column H with value in D (Update Inspection intervals from column D into H)

But 
If A doesn’t match F (Equipment numbers DO NOT match)
AND/ OR 
If B doesn’t match G (ID-Numbers DO NOT match)

Highlight the cell in column A
```

TASK 2

```
If A matches F (Equipment numbers match)
AND
If B matches G (ID-Numbers match)
AND 
If C=1 (Equipment is in Service. C=0 means not in service)
AND
If Column I (Inspection Due date) has a red OR Pink Cell highlighted 

Then
Update Column J with E (Update Inspection date (J) with Last Inspection date (E))
```

Comment: Yes, your question makes sense.

Comment: I have made some edits to make more sense of it. Please see the question again. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: normally people come with some kind of codes or at least show their effort on trying to solve the problem. these kind of question ussually got down vote that turn out no one will try to help you. follow your post. you might dont know vba in excel at all. then even sb try to help, you will not know how to paste the code and excute it. please do your research before asking like this. sincerely

Comment: @DucAnhNguyen
Thank you so much for the advice. i totally agree with you. I am new to this website and will make sure i do what you advised. Thank you sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: After the further information you provided in your comments, I have adjusted the below code, which should now work for task 1, then adjust what I have shown you for task 2:

```
Sub Task_1()
    Dim X As Integer, Y as Integer, LastX as Integer
    For X = 2 to 10000
        If Range("A" & X).Value = "" Then Exit For
    Next X
    LastX = X - 1
    For X = 2 to LastX
        For Y = 2 to LastX
            If Range("F" & Y).Value = Range("A" & X).Value Then
                If Range("G" & Y).Value = Range("B" & X).Value Then
                    If CInt(Range("C" & X).Value) = 1 Then 
                        Range("H" & Y).Value = Range("D" & X).Value
                        GoTo Found_It
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next Y
        Range("A" & X).Interior.Color = vbCyan
Found_It:
    Next X
End Sub
```

Edit: The problems with your code for Task_2 were: 1. You can't have two End Sub as the end of one Sub routine. 2. You must have an End If for any If Then statement that has more than one line. 3. You can combine the And parameter to reduce the number of Nested Ifs. 4. You can name a variable using a parenthesis (brackets are reserved for Array values). The below should now work.

```
Sub Task_2()
    Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer, LastX As Integer
    Dim RGB1 As Long, RGB2 As Long

    RGB1 = RGB(255, 153, 204)
    RGB2 = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    For X = 2 To 10000
        If Range("B" & X).Value = "" Then Exit For
    Next X
    LastX = X - 1
    For X = 2 To LastX
        For Y = 2 To LastX
            If Range("W" & Y).Value = Range("B" & X).Value And Range("N" & Y).Value = Range("D" & X).Value And CInt(Range("E" & X).Value) = 1 Then
                If Range("I" & Y).Interior.Color.RGB = RGB1 Or Range("I" & Y).Interior.Color.RGB = RGB2 Then
                    Range("J" & Y).Value = Range("E" & X).Value
                    GoTo Found_It_2
                End If
            End If
        Next Y
        Range("B" & X).Interior.Color = vbCyan
Found_It_2:
    Next X
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161881/discussion-on-answer-by-sercho-excel-vba-compare-columns-for-matching).